# Extract non-index types from a union

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I could make great use of a type like `Extract<T>` that would resolve to all the types in a union `T` that are NOT `string` or `number`. Is this possible?

`Extract<T, string | number>` will find everything that *extends* `string` or `number`, but I want something that will extract everything this is not *exactly* `string` or `number`.

Some examples of what I want, if the type was named `NonIndex`:

```
NonIndex<string | 1>; // expect 1
NonIndex<'a' | 1>; // expect 'a' | 1
NonIndex<string | 'a'>; // expect 'a'
```

[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgZjAdgEwgDwCrggHgwGljkIFEAbAZwgD4oBeKC4AJwEtEBzKdYCFCqBgBQUKAH4iIqAC4oiAK4BbAEYRm3NL36CpE+FNnkqAbiGhIUAHIB7RElRo8GrcgEBrCCGtwoAQ0QgtAwA3lAA2gDSUOyCALqy8PboWJA4EYSIEABuaoQRtAC+YRixpkKoAMZkvszQFbZM3ACMsjZ2KOg4TGycUAA+UE3UxlAA9KMakBXAg4Qc1tbI5RBVNXUNMxAATK22SY4A5L4H-YPDYxPoUzNHJwNNcwtLldW1UPWIjRAAzLvtDl0WOwuANbudxpMVjdjoRlL4lkA) is the closest I've come in the playground, but you can see it's not right yet. Can it be done?

---

My motivating use case is to (substantially) improve the typing of [`omit()`](https://github.com/simontonsoftware/s-libs/blob/master/projects/micro-dash/src/lib/object/omit.ts) in one of my open source libraries. If you're very brave, you can take a look at my *almost* solution [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdgEwgDwCrmgXigZ2AJwEs4BzKAHyjgFcBbAIwnwG4AoUSWAM3iTQwA8qKCmAREOWIhTpIAGm4KAogBscWKhABuTAHxRseIqRHIxEqKlZQoAfm7WoALip1G+U+YSSrN+zC5HF1V1Ng5oADkAezheFCFPcW8oAGsIECiuKABDOBB9bABvKABtAGkoYksAXRcAuP5IATKFOG0mBTL9AF8S1Gq2dgwoAFU4bK4uCABjMQQy9JwhBQB5WkJgSVEkyTSMrNz8g0dKJTN8bNmBBtkIBT3My10TqDPplWokAQes1FX1za6MLDACy2RAjAAgpMZnMFiAln8oGsNlszDtUulHocCq9zpdgAJHNFYtJkN8sb9dHJHGcCATrmTbv9Uc8gaxWEh3tl8NAuNQ4LNCDEoFEAUSbMJthYovQAFawihQAVILjECAIJU0FQqGk2FaJCyQ-AXEAU-aWJU3DBsgAUjllCtmLj+jgAdB6wNlgAALHAuFasACULkKjnKlTgo3GMNmGvhiNWJRoDCY1V0tUs5QGrG6UAAZI4wzYbBGqmCIRBoVM4-NFstkcm3GmM7YXdm2DZuoMAPQ9qAAWiHw5Ho+HHK5Kh50GmMTwuAILiMxBIbEn06gs7g85TLhT7kG695m7nwFF8tDjmye+bLEc9BcABFvRA2N3WH2oAASM6QWa3KBimvVxUxYKBulYLd5xIKIogQABGAxRQBW1HQUAByeh0KDNhPx-ZA-2AACgLbED3CVFUIDVNoEGYKB6FI58xAo6RqI1OiIKgs8YLggAmJCxQ2VD5QUIwcInGYp2PLjIz4DVL1LFIlwIFdM33JhO1KJSyLTG9QLfXD+3wwjiNKZBlOMEg1NvOiSnMnT8Gs-TwMg08oB4hAAGYBJQ4g5IQDCfUIbDDO-X9YVMuyLNUvSDzM2LdIcjjXO3bjYIQAAWHyhL8lANQUABWcS8PC-9hmKKKF0spy4sq9THISsDOLcjyCuy4BbVy5B8qgdCgvQwriqM0qiPK+KqpipLxvqmqNJcmSPIANnazqyR6sTD0kjcZN5Wd8AQFwACUZiifaBGXUhWlvdkSoIiKxsqi6rMa5KFvSgB2FbdtOgKqvEzktuktzZ1oMAohwDYIAUrTGszJjXyvaLSE0h8ktzULjPuzgKvsmanxfOjUfq16WvSgAOFaQbBiGxAw7IQo-Ya7rK7HptvOGCfm0m4IATkpsVqchumBt6rChrC5nRtZur2fxsQ6OyUinpY1V1Vo+jSPqlWqLVknUvc9L4IABn50HwaFv6MZGyLcdlqB4YVpHV3ol6uf1jz4MQ7BBI6qnzdpqB4PFzGWegHHYbl18cidwnXea93Df472UL9mm7hA4PrYe23QI5+WXam+PoMN7zk6E1OLZTYXM8lm2I-tznFad7W2PVhjGpb3W3eLuD4KysvfYF-306MK7aH+z8lB0fAQF9FccnoKIdCgAB3U6UhwABCKAACFqDPOAojPX1oBiaBGBUKIV+cW03SgAAieh78qSRiHeT4NUjKAT+-jAFHofesBV65DPBsb+UR6LQBQO-JACA3QcluiZbO9cHY5CVipEwlBKKtz1vOeg2RNQD1tBXAOo8QIYTFmwIAA). But beware, it has a lot of typing going on! Everything is working well except the last line, as commented at that link.

Comment: Why do you want this?  Is it the use case mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61047551/typescript-union-of-string-and-string-literals) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51954558/how-can-i-remove-a-wider-type-from-a-union-type-without-removing-its-subtypes-in)?  If not, then could you elaborate?  Maybe there is an alternate solution to your underlying issue.

Comment: Sure. I updated my question to include my actual use case. But it's kind of a lot to take in!

Comment: It looks like you want `KnownKeys` from the second linked question, but the specifics of your `omit` are a bit more than I'd like to wade into.  Note how you can use `KnownKeys` to build a different version of `Omit` that behaves a little better in the face of indexable types, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/rNdpYN).  Whether your use case wants `Omitʹ<T, string>` to remove all *known* string literal keys from `T` as well as any string index is up to you, but you can use `KnownKeys` to do so.  If this constitutes an answer for you I'll write it up.

Comment: Thank you for the pointers and the playground! I'd like `Omit'<T, string>` to leave indexed keys alone (omitting a single, unknown string from `Record<string, any>` is still `Record<string, any>`) and turn known parameters optional (since we don't know which one might have been omitted, if any). Omitting a known string should also leave indexed keys alone, but remove a matching known key.

I'll work with what you gave me so far tonight to see if I can make it come together!

Comment: I tried for a while to get things working, and I learned in the process. Thank you for helping! In the end I decided to compromise and not support the rarest use cases because I just couldn't figure them out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you will always be hobbled by the fact that for

```
type x = string |  'a'
```

`x` simply resolves to `string` because `'a'` is just a specialization of `string`

The same applies for

```
type y = number | 1
```

(i.e. `y` is just `number`)

This makes your last case impossible to solve because:

```
NonIndex<string | 'a'>
```

is interpreted by the type-system as being simply:

```
NonIndex<string>
```

i.e. all knowledge of `'a'` is lost and it, therefore, cannot be extracted.

NOTE:

Types `T` and `U` can be considered equal if `T extends U` and `U extends T`.

I thought I'd nailed it with something along the lines of:

```
type StrictInvExtract<T, U> = T extends U ? (U extends T ? never : T) : T;
type NonIndex<T> = StrictInvExtract<T, string>;
```

but the failure of the last case made me realise all approaches to this are a dead-end.