# Keyof Type with String autocomplete TS

Tags: typescript, keyof

So I was working on a type and wanted to get recommendation of an object's keys, and if I wanted to use another key, the type could fallback to a string type.

I know that the union type with a string basically is the every possible string, so no recommendations are given.

But why while this approach does not work `string | keyof Database`
the following gives the desired result `(string & {}) | DatabaseKeys>` ?

Find more complete example in [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=48&ssc=39&pln=48&pc=62#code/C4TwDgpgBAShCGBjYAVeAjANhAwge0wFcBbAOwB4UoBeKAZ2ACcBLUgcwD4aoBvAWABQUKAAkEAEwiMAXPSas2AbkHCkiCHTp4ZUKiqg4ImTAH5ZAClZhCwWQxbsAlDS5yHS-cXgAPAOrNxYAALMyhSEnQpZQEAX0FBCG8wbWAoVmApADMkaAAReGAMeDpofiEoAHoAKirdIOhSeGJoPEyoYLyAISgqiv1G5rt5dmjhatqUeqhGAha2jqhc7t79GexZACIMhg3Rypq66EYIAEdCDQzxOQLCOihW9qmlnr7y47OLiHEAZULgW8222Au3040O01m93mT06ABo0m1mKlmHdCKQANakPAAd1Ijyk0A6xzSd3geKkM0YUCC8DAkFIChe%20kQhEYx1IwF%20NzogIuIPKYN89SJjxRUHEBSKJRJ%20PFEGyhEwqUy2lFdyWAFlvgA6JnlSQKpWydB4WZkvZggCibNVzU08DYEF1K3KFO0Q3cFoOIjwzUW3XMADcpHRmHg8RxaAAWbUAZmcLuEQV9EFCJrNeIAPmFFZhonEBIJEOGGFBi0QyDyoABBNnwEDkOBIVAYbD4CsUeyM7PoiAgB75QroYoQDhcWgAbX0ZWEwjE8EkOg2KGYdsKxDAG1h%20lUiHUmndUC2q4uTU32-KMQvwhns-ni82PoYAwgW53UDUGi0S%20Tz6ar%20vKAr2nd97ykTZBylAD30-A8lwlIcRzfS9ANvOcJHAo9LWDDldHAaDyl3fdv02CAcNQfDkOEYDyjQ0QMKXAAZPA2Co2dYJIo87ToB0COoi8AF1oiLEtUnLEhSCrWtGHrRsEGQNAsFwAgJPILt2CgHs%20wHSVhxKMduCnWjQIYzYVzXM82KIr9D2PCyNzYmibxMhdMI2J9gBfKyPz3GyfzwP9mkc1CXIfI9IL0vj2N8uDNgQqDgpAwj6NcpdsIgXCUEowDrNio8yIyijIES4zkrApiWO8jjbO43iSqEoA).

Comment: See [the answer to the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61048124/2887218) for an explanation