# How to combine custom type with string literal type

Tags: typescript, types

Let's say I have the following custom type

```
type THue =
  | "red"
  | "orange"
  | "yellow"
  | "lime green"
  | "green"
  | "blue green"
  | "cyan"
  | "sky blue"
  | "blue"
  | "purple"
  | "magenta"
  | "pink";
```

How do I use it to extend the `string` literal type?

I would like to have intellisense for `THue` when typing a string argument, but also allow the user to input other strings like `hsla(0, 100%, 50%, 1)`.

I've tried a couple things like, `string | THue`, but the overall type I see is `string`. Also there seems to be no way of supplying a RegExp type which would be handy for my needs.

Comment: See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61048124/2887218) to the question this duplicates for more information.  If I translate (some of) that answer to this example it yields [this code](https://tsplay.dev/N7g3DN).  Good luck!