# How to get the union type of an interface values (with string enum)?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

How can I achieve the following ?

Given :

```
enum FooEnum1 { 
    Foo = "foo",
};

enum FooEnum2 { 
    Foo = 1,
};

interface FooInterface {
    foo1 : FooEnum1,
    foo2 : FooEnum2,
    foo3 : string,
    foo4 : number,
};
```

I'd like to create the following union type : `FooEnum1 | FooEnum2 | string | number`. This type is the union type of the interface's values.

I am not getting the expected result with the following :

`type FooInterfaceValuesType = FooInterface[keyof FooInterface]` -> `string | number`

If I modify the interface like :

```
interface FooInterface {
    foo1 : FooEnum1,
    foo2 : FooEnum2
};
```

`FooInterfaceValuesType` becomes `FooEnum1 | FooEnum2`

What am I doing wrong ? Thanks.

Comment: `FooEnum1` and `FooEnum2` are subtypes of string and number, so when you put them together in a union, you just get `string | number`.

Comment: ^ @katniss is correct: you're not doing anything wrong, it's just that `FooEnum1 | string` is the same thing as `string`, much like "fruit or an apple" is the same thing as "fruit".  Does that fully address the question? If so, then someone (presumably katniss) will write up an answer (or find a suitable dupe target). If not, what's missing?

Comment: I understand both of your answers. However it doesn't really answer my question because `FooEnum1` is not the same as `string` in the sense that an array of `FooEnum1` is not the same as an array of `string`. I am losing some valuable typings along the way.
Is there any way to achieve what I am looking for ? Meaning `FooInterfaceValuesType` becomes `FooEnum1 | FooEnum2 | string | number`

Comment: ‍♂️ That's how TS works; `FooEnum1 | FooEnum2 | string | number` is identical to `string | number`.  We can't rewrite TS so this is not possible as asked.  Could you maybe [edit] to show a [mre] where the difference matters?  Is it autocomplete or something that's the problem?  Maybe you want https://stackoverflow.com/q/61047551/2887218

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, but agree with the comments that it doesn't really work.

Let's say you want a union of two literal strings, you can do that by `type U = "a" | "b"`. When you have `type U = "a" | "b" | string`, `U` becomes just `string` as it doesn't really make sense, since "a" and "b" are also strings.

Going back to your interface, `foo1` can only be assigned with `FooEnum1.Foo` which is a literal string of "foo". Like the type `U` above, when you create a union of "foo" and string, it just becomes a string. Same goes for `FooEnum2.Foo` and number.